# R igraph - Convert a weighted adjacency matrix into weighted edgelist

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I have a nxm adjacency matrix, where (i,j) represent the score of association between i and j. I need to convert this into the following format like :
`i j <score1>`

using R' igraph package and output it into a text file.

I can derive the edgelist, but its showing up without the weights. I used the following code:

`library(igraph) 
 g <- graph.adjacency(myAdjacencymatrix)
 get.edgelist(g)`

However, it does not show the weights.

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)                # for reproducible example
myAdjacencyMatrix <- matrix(runif(400),nc=20,nr=20)

g  <- graph.adjacency(myAdjacencyMatrix,weighted=TRUE)
df <- get.data.frame(g)
head(df)
#   from to    weight
# 1    1  1 0.2655087
# 2    1  2 0.9347052
# 3    1  3 0.8209463
# 4    1  4 0.9128759
# 5    1  5 0.4346595
# 6    1  6 0.6547239
```

You need to use `weighted=TRUE` in the call to `graph.adjacency(...)` to have weights assigned to the edges. Then, `get.data.frame(...)` will return a data frame of the edges with all edge attributes by default. You can use the `what=...` argument to return, e.g., the vertex list with attributes.

In future: *provide an example, rather than forcing us to create one for you!!!*